# In integration, does $d(x+y) = dx + dy$?

Tags: calculus

This is not 2-dimensional integration, I'm just trying to do substitution of integration variable. I'm using the substitution of $W_t=\tilde{W_t}-{\theta}t$. ${\theta}$ is a constant. Is the following substitution correct?

$$\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{\theta}dW_t=\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{\theta}d(\tilde{W_t}-{\theta}t)=\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{\theta}d\tilde{W_t}-\int_{t=0}^{t=T}{\theta}^2dt$$

Comment: So ... it coincidentally happens that $W_t, \overline {W}_t$ and $t$ all have value $0$ together and all have value $T$ together?

Comment: @PaulSinclair there was a mistake in my boundary condition, i've changed that

Comment: This is true if the integrals are interpreted as Stieltjes integral or its generalizations.

By judging from the notation, however, I suspect that you are actually dealing with stochastic integrals (such as Itô integral). In this case, we still have $\mathrm{d}(X_t+Y_t) = \mathrm{d}X_t + \mathrm{d}Y_t$ if both $X$ and $Y$ are Itô processes with respect to the same Wiener process.

Comment: Actually, since $\theta$ is a constant, Your integrals are all trivial. That is, the integral equation reduces to $$\theta(W_t(T) - W_t(0)) = \theta(\overline W_t(T) - \overline W_t(0))  - \theta^2(T - 0)$$ This equation also follows directly from $W_t=\overline W_t-\theta t$.

Answer (score 0):

Not it in uncorrect, the substitution is valid is we are assuming fro example that $\tilde{W_t}=\tilde{W_t}(t)$ and then

$$W_t=\tilde{W_t}-{\theta}t \implies dW_t=\tilde{W_t'}dt-{\theta}dt$$

moreover we also need that the transformation is bijective and in order to change the limits of integration we need to solve

- $W_t=\tilde{W_t}-{\theta}t=0 \implies t=t_0$
- $W_t=\tilde{W_t}-{\theta}t=T \implies t=t_T$

and then

$$\int_0^T{\theta}dW_t=\int_0^T{\theta}d(\tilde{W_t}-{\theta}t)=\int_{t_0}^{t_T}\left({\theta}\tilde{W_t'}-{\theta}^2\right)dt$$

Comment: I agree with yours, but look carefully, $d(\tilde{W_t}) = \tilde{W}'_t dt$, right?, I just did not expend $d(\tilde{W_t})$ further. So i guess mine is correct too.

Comment: $W_t$ is the integrating variable in the first integral, then we need to define what is the new variable, in my example I'm assuming $t$ as new variables, we can't use$ 2$ different variables.

Comment: there was a mistake in my boundary condition, i've changed that in the question, all the boundary is meant for the value of t